# How to call a multidimensional table from one function to another one

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am trying to call a multidimensional table from one function to another one but I get the error :

> Sub or Function not defined

here is what I tried :

```
Public Function update()

Public tabPerformance(11, 16) As Long

If (Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("E3").Value = "Performance") Then

    For j = 0 To j = 1
        For i = 0 To i = 1
            For k = 3 To 5

                For l = 6 To 8

                    tabPerformance(j, i) = Cells(l, k).Value

                    MsgBox tabPerformance(j, i)

                Next l

            Next k
        Next i
    Next j

End If

If (Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("E3").Value = "Inflation") Then

    For j = 0 To j = 1
        For i = 0 To i = 1
            For k = 3 To 5

                For l = 6 To 8

                    tabInflation(j, i) = Cells(l, k).Value

                    MsgBox tabInflation(j, i)

                Next l

            Next k
        Next i
    Next j

End If
```

and this is the function where I want to call the tabPerformance Table :

```
Public Function recap()

Dim tabPerformanceCells(11, 16) As Long
If (Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("E3").Value = "Performance") Then

    For j = 0 To j = 1
        For i = 0 To i = 1
            For k = 3 To 5

                For l = 6 To 8

                    Cells(l, k).Value = tabPerformance(j, i)

                    MsgBox Cells(l, k).Value

                Next l

            Next k
        Next i
    Next j

End If
```

I need to know how to properly call the tabPerformance from anywhere i want.

Comment: `tabPerformance` is an array variable (not a function you "call"), so it needs to be defined outside of the function, not within it if you want it to be Public.

Comment: `For j = 0 To j = 1` is wrong syntax. It doesn't execute. The correct syntax is `For j = 0 To 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four things you should know about when developing VBA code.

1. Put 'Option Explicit' at the start of each Module/Class'.  This will make sure that you don't get errors because of incorrect syntax of misspelled variable names.
2. In the VBA IDE if you press F1 when the cursor is on a VBA keyword this will bring up the MS Help Page for that feature in VBA. This should be your first port of call for any errors you see. Try this for the F'or' keyword and you will see that your syntax for the For loop is incorrect.
3. Before you run any code make sure you compile the whole project so that you can find errors that are not detected by Option Explicit.  (Debug.Compile Project)
4. Install the fantastic RubberDuck addin for VBA.  Its free software.  RubberDuck will help keep your code nicely indented, allow you to rename things safely and  produce 'Code Inspections' which is where a stricter analysis of the VBA code is done and advice is given on how to write your code more safely.